# $_FILES remains empty

Tags: php, file

I'm trying to add an upload feature in an existing Wordpress plugin. But the file seems not to load. I use this code in the form:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
// other code of existing plugin.
<input type="submit" value="plugin submit" id="plugin submit" name="plugin submit">
</form>
```

Then in the function of the plugin I put the test line for knowing what happens:

```
 if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }
    else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
    echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
    }
```

I enter in else branch but all fields are empty. What am I missing?

Comment: Shouldn't you specify the php page in the `action` part of the form?

Answer (score 0):

You will hit the else branch even if `$_FILES` is undefined.

You can first check that the user uploaded a file.

`is_uploaded_file()`

> Returns TRUE if the file named by filename was uploaded via HTTP POST.

You can use somthing like:
`if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])`

But since it seems this will not return `TRUE` in your case I must ask - since your form is `POST`ing to the same page that it is on - is your PHP code at the top of the page where your form resides? If that is the case don't you find it odd that it outputs the blank upload information even before you upload?

Comment: Thanks. As you say the function return FALSE. I do not understand you. The form is in a page, the action that the plugin do, is on another php file. Oh... maybe because in the file I have to add session_start() to register the $_POST of the form?

Comment: You need to make sure that your form `POST`s to the location that will preform the "fuction of the plugin". In your code the form `POST`s to the same page that it is on - `action=""` therefore the code that handles the upload must be on the same page as the form.

Comment: Thanks. So I have to put the upload code on the same page of the form or I use action ="page of the plugin work" and put there the code.
I will try tomorrow and tell you how it happens

Comment: Hello, I have tried to put the full path in action ="file in which plugin do stuff.php" but the if I use
if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']))
    echo "OK : ".$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
else "ERROR";
It does not print anything, than I have the same Upload, Size and Store in blank. 
And the plugin works fine.

Comment: Do you mean that it returns `FALSE`?

Comment: Sorry, I am dumb. I forgot the word echo.
So yeah, it returns     FALSE.

Comment: show me the output of `var_dump($_FILES);` on the action page.

Comment: array(0) { }
It does not upload the file

Comment: I think your form is being submitted by javascript. Check your browser console and verify. Or change the action to gibberish and see if it still posts to the same place.

Comment: Hi, I think it is not. But probably I have done some mistakes in explanation earlier. I have found that my form is contained in a bigger form with action ="". So when I do the submit, in another file, that I think is included in the first page but I do not know how because I do not see any includes, the $_POST is catched with if (isset($_POST['submit'])) -> do stuff I expect. So if I use action ="" should It work? Or could not I use a form in a form?
I do not know what to think

Comment: You should not nest forms.

Comment: Ok thank you very much.
Maybe I add another page with uploads form after the plugin has done its stuff.
Simpler and clearer